Expo unable to resolve module expo-router
I'm new to React Native so I'm hoping this is a simple problem with a solution I've just overlooked, but I'm getting an error every time I start a new project. I fiddle with it for a bit, sometimes fixes found here and here work, but somethings they don't. I returned to a project that I thought I had fixed and the error is back and won't go away. I'd try to provide a reproduction but it literally happens as soon as I initialize an new project. (Edit) I'm using Expo Go. Here's the error:
Unable to resolve module ./node_modules/expo-router/entry from /Users/[me]/Documents/[03] Code/[app]/.: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)
  * node_modules/expo-router/entry/index(.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.mjs|.native.mjs|.mjs|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.css|.native.css|.css)

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
0x0


Are you using Expo Go, or a development build?
If you're using Expo Go, try to shift to a development build.
If you're using a dev build, try completely deleting ios/ and android/ folders and the node_modules/ along with the package manager's lockfile. Then,

reinstall everything: npm i
check your package versions: npx expo install --check
build the ios/ and android/ folders again: npx expo prebuild
run the build: npx expo run:ios/npx expo run:android


Using Expo Go, I'll try the same with dev build.

In case this helps anyone, after tracking this down on our end: Another possibility is that this could be failing on the Expo / EAS side if someone accidentally checks a package-lock.json file into a repository that's expecting to build with eg. pnpm-lock.json, and the dependencies get out of sync.
For example, if a new dependency is added to package.json and a new pnpm-lock.json is installed, package-lock.json will not change but Expo may attempt a build with the NPM lockfile.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
